# Date range grouping per month

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have this kind of data in SQL Server

```
Person  StartDate                  EndDate                  Value
-----------------------------------------------------------------
38523   2013-01-10 22:00:00.000    2013-01-10 22:59:00.000  0.064
38523   2013-01-10 23:00:00.000    2013-01-10 23:59:00.000  0.065
38523   2013-01-12 00:00:00.000    2013-01-12 00:59:00.000  0.068
38523   2013-01-12 01:00:00.000    2013-01-12 01:59:00.000  0.069
38523   2013-01-12 02:00:00.000    2013-01-12 02:59:00.000  0.069
38523   2013-01-12 03:00:00.000    2013-01-12 03:59:00.000  0.069
38523   2013-01-31 23:00:00.000    2013-01-31 23:59:00.000  0.061
38523   2013-02-01 00:00:00.000    2013-02-01 00:59:00.000  0.064
```

I need grouping in such a way that continuous values should be grouped together per month.
If there is a gap more than 1 minutes between previous end date and next start date then that should be split into separate group.

Expected result:

```
Person  StartDate                  EndDate                  Sum(Value)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
38523   2013-01-10 22:00:00.000    2013-01-10 23:59:00.000  0.129
38523   2013-01-12 00:00:00.000    2013-01-12 03:59:00.000  0.275
38523   2013-01-31 23:00:00.000    2013-01-31 23:59:00.000  0.061 (even though continuity exists, month was end hence separate record)
38523   2013-02-01 00:00:00.000    2013-02-01 00:59:00.000  0.064
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: And what have you tried already?

Comment: can you please explain this "If there is a gap more than 1 minutes between previous end date and next start date then that should be split into separate group."

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, DateCreated) as varchar(10)) + '/' 
        + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, DateCreated) as varchar(10))
FROM [Reporting].[dbo].[Hmis_Forms]
GROUP BY 
    CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, DateCreated) as varchar(10)) + '/' 
        + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, DateCreated) as varchar(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just basing on your data and expected result, may the following query help you:

```
SELECT 
    Person, 
    MIN(StartDate) as StartDate, 
    MAX(EndDate) as EndDate, 
    SUM(Value)
FROM table
GROUP BY 
    Person, 
    CAST(StartDate as date)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar, maybe this can help you:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test2 
(
    Person int, 
    StartDate datetime, 
    EndDate datetime, 
    Value numeric (12, 3), 
    NextDate datetime
);


INSERT INTO #Test2(Person, StartDate, EndDate, Value, NextDate)
SELECT 
    Person, 
    StartDate, 
    EndDate, 
    Value, 
    (SELECT TOP 1 StartDate FROM Test WHERE StartDate > t.EndDate ORDER BY StartDate, EndDate)  
FROM Test t



SELECT 
    MAX(StartDate) ,
    MAX(EndDate) ,
    SUM(Value)


FROM #Test2
GROUP BY 
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, NextDate, EndDate)

ORDER BY 
    MAX(StartDate) ,
    MAX(EndDate)    
DROP TABLE #Test2
```

What am I done is that I create temp table with new column which keep next starting date value. Then, i grouped values based on substract of start and end date, counting in minutes.

I get same row like your results, except of sum.